# What's the storage limit of Diigo?

Tags: online-storage, diigo

Anyone uses Diigo here?

I've heard it can store pictures, docs, notes, bookmarks, songs, and I was thinking of trying it.. but does anyone know what's the storage limit ?

Nowhere did it state it's storage limit at all, but it'd just seems unlikely that they would give arbitrary storage for pics / docs / notes / songs / etc.

I mean if it's just 5GB then I'd wouldn't bother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a free account you can't store very much - up to 30 images and cache 30 web pages. If you pay for a premium plan ($5 a month or $40 a year at time of writing), then it is unlimited. Full details are available on the [pricing page](http://www.diigo.com/premium/pricing_table_details).

Diigo isn't so much pitched at being a storage service as an enhanced bookmarking / organising service. More akin to [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/) than Dropbox and the like.

Comment: Hmm *"Unlimited"*... What's the catch?

Comment: You only really get to store bookmarks, web pages and images so you'd be hard pressed to use a lot. Storage isn't expensive in any case, $40 a year will get you over 30GB of Amazon storage and $99 will get you 100GB on Dropbox.

Comment: *Unlimited* storage of images.. hmmm, actually *everything* could be an image. We could have a 2gb video file converted to an image.